# Github API v3 doesn't show all user repositories

Tags: curl, github-api

If i type this command:

```
$ curl https://api.github.com/users/KiCad/repos | grep full_name
```

I expect that it will return all KiCad repositories, but it returns:

```
"full_name": "KiCad/Air_Coils_SML_NEOSID.pretty",
"full_name": "KiCad/Buzzers_Beepers.pretty",
"full_name": "KiCad/Capacitors_Elko_ThroughHole.pretty",
"full_name": "KiCad/Capacitors_SMD.pretty",
"full_name": "KiCad/Capacitors_Tantalum_SMD.pretty",
"full_name": "KiCad/Capacitors_ThroughHole.pretty",
"full_name": "KiCad/Choke_Axial_ThroughHole.pretty",
"full_name": "KiCad/Choke_Common-Mode_Wurth.pretty",
"full_name": "KiCad/Choke_Radial_ThroughHole.pretty",
"full_name": "KiCad/Choke_SMD.pretty",
"full_name": "KiCad/Choke_Toroid_ThroughHole.pretty",
"full_name": "KiCad/Connect.pretty",
"full_name": "KiCad/Connectors_Molex.pretty",
"full_name": "KiCad/Converters_DCDC_ACDC.pretty",
"full_name": "KiCad/Crystals.pretty",
"full_name": "KiCad/Crystals_Oscillators_SMD.pretty",
"full_name": "KiCad/Diodes_SMD.pretty",
"full_name": "KiCad/Diodes_ThroughHole.pretty",
"full_name": "KiCad/Discret.pretty",
"full_name": "KiCad/Display.pretty",
"full_name": "KiCad/Displays_7-Segment.pretty",
"full_name": "KiCad/Divers.pretty",
"full_name": "KiCad/EuroBoard_Outline.pretty",
"full_name": "KiCad/Fiducials.pretty",
"full_name": "KiCad/Filters_HF_Coils_NEOSID.pretty",
"full_name": "KiCad/Fuse_Holders_and_Fuses.pretty",
"full_name": "KiCad/Hall-Effect_Transducers_LEM.pretty",
"full_name": "KiCad/Heatsinks.pretty",
"full_name": "KiCad/Housings_DFN_QFN.pretty",
"full_name": "KiCad/Housings_QFP.pretty",
```

If you look at https://github.com/KiCad, you will see, that there are more repositories.

Has anyone encountered this problem? How do you solve it?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The GitHub API uses pagination and defaults to 30 items per page. You will have to use

```
curl -i https://api.github.com/users/KiCad/repos?per_page=100
```

100 is the most number of items you can get on a single page. With `-i` specified you'll see headers printed out and the header you're looking for is the `Links` header. That will have links to help you navigate the pages. One of those links should look like

```
https://api.github.com/users/KiCad/repos?per_page=100&page=2
```

So if you do

```
curl -i https://api.github.com/users/KiCad/repos?per_page=100&page=2
```

You'll get repos 101-200. You can continue this until there is no `next` link in the `Links` header or until you realize you've received fewer than 100 results.

Comment: This answer is great, and here's a link to the relevant documenation on pagination for more details https://developer.github.com/v3/#pagination